# Tablix row sum by one column value

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix with two columns. One is for tax rate (0%, 5%, 10%... - `=Fields!TaxRate.Value`), other for total tax values (`=Fields!TotalTax.Value`).

In my report I receive these values as:

1. Tax rate 20%  -  $500
2. Tax rate 5%  -  $20
3. Tax rate 20% - $450
4. Tax rate 5% - $25

How can I put all the same tax rates in one row and sum up the values, by same tax rate, such that the result is:

1. Tax rate 20%  - $950
2. Tax rate 5%  - $45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a **Group** based on `TaxRate` to the **Tablix**. The **Group** will be grouped on `Fields!TaxRate.Value`. When adding the **Group**, make sure to include a Header or Footer.

In the Header or Footer row that's created, you can add a field with the expression `=Sum(Fields!TotalTax.Value)`, which will display the total tax for each different `TaxValue` **Group**.

See [Add or Delete a Group in a Data Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156487%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for specific implementation details.